# How to use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)?

Tags: httpclient, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, mfrc522

I am trying to POST some data from a MFRC522 RFID Scanner to a webpage and I am getting errors in running the below code. Please advise; any help would be highly appreciated. The error that I am getting on the Arduino IDE is as follows:

TEST_NodeMCU_V3_RFID_RC522_DB.ino: In function 'void loop()':
TEST_NodeMCU_V3_RFID_RC522_DB:79:15: error: call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)

79 |     http.begin("http://192.168.0.0/Folder_Name/file.php");  //Specify request destination

exit status 1

call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//THIS LIBRARY IS NOT BEING DETECTED DESPITE HAVING INSTALLED!!!//
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
#define SS_PIN D2  //--> SDA / SS is connected to pinout D2
#define RST_PIN D1  //--> RST is connected to pinout D1
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);  //--> Create MFRC522 instance.

#define ON_Board_LED 2  //--> Defining an On Board LED, used for indicators when the process of connecting to a wifi router
//----------------------------------------SSID and Password of your WiFi router-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
const char* ssid = "your_wifi_name"; //your_wifi_name
const char* password = "your_wifi_password"; //your_wifi_password
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

ESP8266WebServer server(80);  //--> Server on port 80

int readsuccess;
byte readcard[4];
char str[32] = "";
String StrUID;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------SETUP--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); //--> Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();      //--> Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); //--> Init MFRC522 card

  delay(500);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //--> Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");
    
  pinMode(ON_Board_LED,OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led On Board

  //----------------------------------------Wait for connection
  Serial.print("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
  }
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If successfully connected to the wifi router, the IP Address that will be visited is displayed in the serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("Please tag a card or keychain to see the UID !");
  Serial.println("");
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------LOOP---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly
  readsuccess = getid();
 
  if(readsuccess) {  
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    HTTPClient http;    //Declare object of class HTTPClient
 
    String UIDresultSend, postData;
    UIDresultSend = StrUID;
   
    //Post Data
    postData = "UIDresult=" + UIDresultSend;

    // ERRORR IS BEING GIVEN ON LINE BELOW//
    http.begin("http://192.168.0.0/Folder_Name/file.php");  //Specify request destination
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //Specify content-type header
   
    int httpCode = http.POST(postData);   //Send the request
    String payload = http.getString();    //Get the response payload
  
    Serial.println(UIDresultSend);
    Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
    Serial.println(payload);    //Print request response payload
    
    http.end();  //Close connection
    delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
  }
}

//----------------------------------------Procedure for reading and obtaining a UID from a card or keychain---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
int getid() {  
  if(!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return 0;
  }
  if(!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return 0;
  }
 
  
  Serial.print("THE UID OF THE SCANNED CARD IS : ");
  
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    readcard[i]=mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]; //storing the UID of the tag in readcard
    array_to_string(readcard, 4, str);
    StrUID = str;
  }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  return 1;
}

//----------------------------------------Procedure to change the result of reading an array UID into a string------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
void array_to_string(byte array[], unsigned int len, char buffer[]) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        byte nib1 = (array[i] >> 4) & 0x0F;
        byte nib2 = (array[i] >> 0) & 0x0F;
        buffer[i*2+0] = nib1  < 0xA ? '0' + nib1  : 'A' + nib1  - 0xA;
        buffer[i*2+1] = nib2  < 0xA ? '0' + nib2  : 'A' + nib2  - 0xA;
    }
    buffer[len*2] = '\0';
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Kind regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68374278/18139310 Found the working solution. Thanks community :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the developers removed the normal function with the comment "old API is now explicitly forbidden"

So one now has to create an empty "WiFiClient" Object and pass it, like this:

```
String fixedHttpCall(String url){
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
        HTTPClient http;
        {
            WiFiClient client;
            http.begin(client, url.c_str());
        }
        int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
        if (httpResponseCode>0) {
            Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
            Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
            String payload = http.getString();
            Serial.println(payload);
            return payload;
        }else {
            Serial.print("Error code: ");
            Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```